# Objects in InDesign not changing opacity

Tags: adobe-indesign, transparency

I have been working in the same document the past few days with no issues. even this morning everything was working normally. I was using a few objects with lighter opacity applied to them.

All of a sudden every object that had an opacity applied to it was displaying at 100% opacity. When I try to go back and adjust the objects opacity, nothing visibly happens.

Maybe I hit something on the keyboard and changed a setting unknowingly?

Any ideas as to what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Hello, can you adjust the opacity of objects in a new document? I am not aware of any keyboard shortcuts that would prevent changing opacity, but you could always try resetting your preferences. What does your effects panel look like?

Comment: Yes they changed in a different document. I actually just closed out of my indesign and reopened the file, and everything is working like normal. Just curious as to how my settings were changed so easily...

Comment: Not sure. When in doubt, close out and open.

Comment: Closeout and open your InDesign, and it should resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Seems like you are switched to "Fast Display" setting. I tried it on a file and it produced the same results as you are expecting.

[image]

============= Previous Answer ================

Generally I would look two places before blaming it to Low Graphics Memory and neeeding to restart the computer.

View and Window menu: Has certain switches to turn on and off non-printing items and proofing tools.

Preferences: If I've changed anything there.

You can try restart the Computer if everything seems in place.

Comment: Generally, you begin from user error. Mainly because you can do something about that. You dont blame the system, hardware etc unless you have somedeep understanding of these and have some way of verifying a claim. Anyway where in the post does the op say its a graphics memory issue?

Comment: By blaming I mean, sometimes the user has a smaller GPU than recommended and it works most of the time but often create unwanted results. Thanks for your recommendations. I’d try to improve my answer.

Comment: Indesign isnt very resource heavy so it shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: How many Graphics cards have you been using?

Comment: Does not matter indesign works even without graphics acceleration. But realistically even the shittiest graphics card today is better than best cards 10 years ago. Hell even my phone is having a decent graphics card but yes the number of graphics cards ive used is in the hundreds of different models.

Comment: I don’t know what are you trying to prove here. Indesign has a set of settings where you can see things in draft quality or full res quality. If Indesign is so lightweight on gfx cards then why these settings are present in the first place. I’ve noticed even software crashes because of less GPU memory. If you need to learn about it, try Google.

Comment: Im just pointing out that you cant start by saying anything about blaming graphics card memory. Because nobody has introduced a blame on gfx card memory in first place. Then you need to  start with a sentence of why its reasonable. But you are not doing so. In anycase if its a gfx card memory issue then you would have a lot of other random problems every day ir if you just run out then it would be slow. So not a valid argument in first place, but hard to say as you dont present why itseven valid in this discussion.

Comment: Before needing to restart the computer due to lack of graphics memory, I’d look into these places. That’s what I said and there was a reason. I thanked you and committed to make my answers better. There was nothing illogical that could possibly offend you. On your end, there was no need to advocate the Software or Gfx cards. I have few years of experience using these. Anyways I sincerly thank you again so I could some time to mend my mistakes.

Comment: Its not offensive, its a propaganda trick for undermining trust into something. If you see stuff written like this often check your sources carefully. Theres no need for that all you need to do is. Introduce the possibility that its a harware issue. I cant just start my discussion by saying: "Before we blame carrots, ..." If nobody has blamed anything.

Comment: You are right. The problem with the rapidly evolving technology is that often several things are overlooked. Look at this example: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/graphic-glitches-indesign-cc/td-p/9520960. In another example (Not with adobe) I recently nearly destroyed one of a very valuable file but the problem had nothing to do with the user error but the application failed to address a problem which was creating unwanted results.

Comment: Specially Adobe has introduced graphics intensive features in its flagship products thus increased the requirements of the GPU as well. One of my machine is relatively older and often have to face the problems that are not user specific. Probably that's why the debate even started. Anyhow. I hope that the problem would be solved with my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Save your file, close it, and try updating InDesign in creative cloud. When I reopened the application, it worked again.